# PHP PDO #1062 - Duplicate entry for key 'fkss'

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

help my proplem when insert in tabel mysql
my structure table:
[image]

when insert in table error here...
[image]

please solution..

Comment: Please provide the insert query in your question. The image is not giving the full query.

Comment: remove idx from your query, because it is an autoincrement

Comment: Remove the column first and then create again

Comment: @Jens my query "INSERT INTO siswa_sekolah SET id_sekolah = '".$_POST['id_sekolah']."' , user_id = '".$_POST['user_id']."', id_kelas = '".$_POST['id_kelas']."' , id_rombel = '".$_POST['id_rombel']."', id_tahun_ajar = '".$_POST['id_tahun_ajar']."' "; im not use idx in query

Comment: Insert into .... set ... is not valid Syntax. Also the query is not the same as in your screenshot

Comment: thanks @Jens problem solved

Comment: Screenshots are almost always the wrong way to present this information. For database questions please post the query you're trying to execute *in full* and **as plain text**. This helps people because they can cut, paste, and make corrections. For the schema use the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` which gives the right level of technical detail.

Answer (score 0):

This error says, the new record has an existing record into the table you are working. Please check your primary key before inserting it as a new record.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: primery key in set field 'idx' and auto increment, why not working where insert existing value record 'user_id' ?

Comment: @Iyesboy means u set your user_id as unique and the record for IDS0000702 already exist

Comment: i try insert live in phpmyadmin,

Comment: Yeah it means record is already exist at your current working table in DB

Answer (score 0):

It tells you that `IDS0000702` is already used in your table. Make sure the column that holds  that kind of id (which I guess the `user_id` column) is not unique (if not intended to save data uniquely):

```
//if you want to change your "suspecting" column's attribute
ALTER TABLE mytable DROP INDEX mycolumn
```

Comment: i try to "ALTER TABLE `siswa_sekolah` DROP INDEX `user_id`" the comment "#1091 - Can't DROP 'user_id'; check that column/key exists "

Comment: @Iyesboy Then maybe I was wrong of assuming that suspecting column is `user_id`. I dunno know the whole of your table. Why not try the other id-holding columns, specially that `fkss` (which is cannot be seen in the photos you've posted)

Answer (score 0):

thanks all....  **PROBLEM SOLVED** two step for resolved problem:

1. Show index in table query = `SHOW INDEX FROM <table_name>;`
2. Delete index in table = `ALTER TABLE <table_name> DROP INDEX <index_name>;`

im found the index in user_id "fkss"
thanks any answer.. :)
[link refernce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823322/1062-duplicate-entry-for-key-unique-id-when-trying-to-add-unique-key-my)