# liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Duplicate entry

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc, liquibase

I'm getting bellow Exception while running production environment.but work fine in locally.

```
ing bean with name 'jobLauncher' defined in class path resource [config/spring/batch/lms-draw-result-batch-jobs-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jobRepository' while setting bean property 'jobRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository' defined in class path resource [config/spring/batch/lms-draw-result-batch-jobs-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [config/spring/lms-txnconfig-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [config/spring/lms-dbconfig-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is `liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set db/changelog/db.changelog-1.7.xml:`:update-draw-id-to-winning_result::Mohamed Musni:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Duplicate entry '1340' for key 'draw_id' [Failed SQL: ALTER TABLE lms_staging.winning_result ADD UNIQUE (draw_id)]
2017-08-01 15:06:35 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  SchedulerFactoryBean:765 - Shutting down Quartz Scheduler
2017-08-01 15:06:35 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  QuartzScheduler:694 - Scheduler org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_$_NON_CLUSTERED shutting down.
2017-08-01 15:06:35 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  QuartzScheduler:613 - Scheduler org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_$_NON_CLUSTERED paused.
2017-08-01 15:06:35 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  QuartzScheduler:771 - Scheduler org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_$_NON_CLUSTERED shutdown complete.
2017-08-01 15:06:35 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  ThreadPoolTaskScheduler:203 - Shutting down ExecutorService 'messageBrokerTaskScheduler'
2017-08-01 15:06:35 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  ThreadPoolTaskExecutor:203 - Shutting down ExecutorService 'brokerChannelExecutor'
2017-08-01 15:06:35 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  ThreadPoolTaskExecutor:203 - Shutting down ExecutorService 'clientOutboundChannelExecutor'
2017-08-01 15:06:35 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  ThreadPoolTaskExecutor:203 - Shutting down ExecutorService 'clientInboundChannelExecutor'
2017-08-01 15:06:35 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  ThreadPoolTaskExecutor:203 - Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskExecutor'
2017-08-01 15:06:35 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR ContextLoader:353 - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'schedulerController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.auxenta.lms.service.DrawManagementService com.auxenta.lms.controller.web.v1.SchedulerController.drawManagementService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'drawManagementServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher com.auxenta.lms.service.Impl.DrawManagementServiceImpl.jobLauncher; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobLauncher' defined in class path resource [config/spring/batch/lms-draw-result-batch-jobs-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jobRepository' while setting bean property 'jobRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository' defined in class path resource [config/spring/batch/lms-draw-result-batch-jobs-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [config/spring/lms-txnconfig-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [config/spring/lms-dbconfig-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set db/changelog/db.changelog-1.7.xml::update-draw-id-to-winning_result::Mohamed Musni:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Duplicate entry '1340' for key 'draw_id' [Failed SQL: ALTER TABLE lms_staging.winning_result ADD UNIQUE (draw_id)]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4961)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5455)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:634)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1074)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1858)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

**here is the my createTable xml file**

```
<changeSet author="zzzzzzzzzz" id="1-create-winning_result">
        <createTable tableName="winning_result">
            <column autoIncrement="true" name="id" type="INT">
                <constraints primaryKey="true"/>
            </column>
            <column name="draw_id" type="INT"/>
            <column name="winning_numbers" type="VARCHAR(45)"/>
            <column name="bonus_numbers" type="VARCHAR(45)"/>
            <column name="special_numbers" type="VARCHAR(45)"/>
            <column name="approved" type="BIT(1)"/>
            <column name="timestamp" type="datetime"/>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
```

Here is ForeignKeyConstraint also,

```
 <changeSet author="zzzzzzzzzz" id="2-add-foreign-constraint">
        <addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="draw_id"
                                 baseTableName="winning_result"
                                 constraintName="fk_draw_winning_result"
                                 deferrable="false"
                                 initiallyDeferred="false" onDelete="NO ACTION"
                                 onUpdate="NO ACTION" referencedColumnNames="id"
                                 referencedTableName="draw"/>
    </changeSet>
```

I need to make draw_id to unique.my (db/changelog/db.changelog-1.7.xml) file  --->

```
            <addUniqueConstraint
                                 columnNames="draw_id"
                                 deferrable="true"
                                 disabled="true"
                                 initiallyDeferred="true"
                                 tableName="winning_result"/>
        </changeSet>
```

is this data base version issue or else other.can anyone helps to me.

Comment: Doesn't the error message state what is wrong? `Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Duplicate entry '1340' for key 'draw_id' [Failed SQL: ALTER TABLE lms_staging.winning_result ADD UNIQUE (draw_id)]`. It seems like you already have some draw_id's in the table that are not unique.

Comment: can i fix this with previous data or need to remove the duplicate @MadsT

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823322/1062-duplicate-entry-for-key-unique-id-when-trying-to-add-unique-key-my)

Answer (score 2):

Adding restrictions to a table with pre-existing data is a dangerous game.

Your winning_result table probably already contains some data and the column you try to make unique (draw_id) contains value 1340 more than once.

You have to either fix the data before adding the constraint (remove the duplicate 1340 na possibly other values) or give up on adding the constraint.

Comment: yep removed duplicated values.that issue fixed.but i got  another issue on this.previously there is ForeignKeyConstraint to  draw_id in winning_result table.when i  adding UniqueConstraint its gone in QA environment.but locally it's not romoving and working fine.may I know any way to fix this.anything abt version problem or else other  @David Vonka

Comment: can i add  UniqueConstraint without affecting ForeignKeyConstraint @David Vonka