# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: Duplicate entry 'B' for key qr_codes_encoded_key_unique

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have already visited following question.

[#1062 - Duplicate entry '' for key 'unique_id' When Trying to add UNIQUE KEY (MySQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823322/1062-duplicate-entry-for-key-unique-id-when-trying-to-add-unique-key-my)

I have made an string column 'encoded_key' as unique. I have inserted 'b' in that column at first and then I want to add 'B' in the column. I think 'b' and 'B' are different and unique but it shows following error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'B' for key 'qr_codes_encoded_key_unique'

Are cases ignored in unique constraint in mysql ?

I am using mysql in laravel application.

Any kind of suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6448861/2210137

Comment: @msfoster Okay I will see.

Comment: @msfoster stil same issue after changing collation to utf8_bin

Comment: Please provide a fiddle.

Comment: @msfoster I am not familiar with fiddle and I don't know how to use that

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5769eb/1
Works as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

u need to change or set custom collation to `utf8_bin`

```
 $table->string('encoded_key')->unique()->collation('utf8_bin');
```

you may also specify character with collation

for example : set `utf8` also like this

```
$table->string('encoded_key')->unique()->charset('utf8')->collation('utf8_bin');
```

for more information read this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558707/case-sensitive-collation-in-mysql)