# Remove duplicate rows based on specific columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates

I have a table that contains these columns:

```
ID (varchar)
SETUP_ID (varchar)
MENU (varchar)
LABEL (varchar)
```

The thing I want to achieve is to remove all duplicates from the table based on two columns `(SETUP_ID, MENU)`.

Table I have:

```
id  |  setup_id  |  menu  |  label  |
-------------------------------------
1   |    10      |  main  |  txt    |
2   |    10      |  main  |  txt    |
3   |    11      | second |  txt    |
4   |    11      | second |  txt    |
5   |    12      | third  |  txt    |
```

Table I want:

```
id  |  setup_id  |  menu  |  label  |
-------------------------------------
1   |    10      |  main  |  txt    |
3   |    11      | second |  txt    |
5   |    12      | third  |  txt    |
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17857710/delete-duplicate-rows-in-large-postgresql-database-table

Comment: This does not answer the question. It offers a solution to create a new table.

Comment: @VynlJunkie that's why I posted a comment and not an answer

Comment: The task is not fully clear, while we don't know whether `setup_id`or `menu` can be NULL. And how to deal with NULL values if possible. Also, please *always* declare your version of Postgres, and tell us whether performance matters. If so, roughly how many rows in the table, roughly how many dupes? Finally, do you just want to select distinct rows, or actively delete dupes from the table?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with a common table expression (cte)

```
with cte as ( 
           select id, setup_id, menu, 
                  row_number () over (partition by setup_id, menu, label) rownum
           from atable )
delete from atable a
where id in (select id from cte where rownum >= 2)
```

This will give you your desired output.

[Common Table Expression docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html)

Comment: I think the `label` should not be included in the window definition, if I understand the OP's requirement correctly.
Also, `rownum = 2` assumes that there can be at most one duplicate row for a given `(setup_id, menu)` tuple. To only keep one row when it's duplicated (however many times), you should use `where rownum >= 2`.

Comment: Good spot, updated to remove label.

Comment: Writing subquery is a bad idea in the performance point of view.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a table named `tbl` where both `setup_id` and `menu` are defined `NOT NULL` and `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY`.
[`EXISTS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) will do nicely:

```sql
DELETE FROM tbl t0
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM tbl t1
   WHERE  t1.setup_id = t0.setup_id
   AND    t1.menu = t0.menu
   AND    t1.id < t0.id
   );
```

This deletes every row where a dupe with lower `id` is found, effectively only keeping the row with the smallest `id` from each set of dupes. An index on `(setup_id, menu)` or even `(setup_id, menu, id)` will help performance with big tables *a lot*.

If there is no PK and no reliable `UNIQUE` (combination of) column(s), you can fall back to using the `ctid`. If NULL values can be involved, you need to specify how to deal with those.
Consider:

- [Delete duplicate rows from small table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583916/delete-duplicate-rows-from-small-table/63759611#63759611)
- [How to delete duplicate rows without unique identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26769454/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-without-unique-identifier/26773018#26773018)
- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129)

**After** cleaning up duplicates, add a `UNIQUE` constraint to prevent new dupes:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD CONSTRAINT tbl_setup_id_menu_uni UNIQUE (setup_id, menu);
```

If you had an index on `(setup_id, menu)`, drop that now. It's superseded by the `UNIQUE` constraint.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution that fits me the best.
Here it is if anyone needs it:

```
DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE id IN
  (SELECT id
   FROM
       (SELECT id,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY setup_id,
     menu
    ORDER BY  id ) AS row_num
        FROM table_name ) t
   WHERE t.row_num > 1 );
```

Comment: Vaild. But (like some other proposed solutions here) much more expensive than necessary.

Comment: In RedShift, this approach worked rather than the (perhaps more intuitive) approach @VynlJunkie [provided earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70448688/8162025).

Answer (score 1):

link: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-union.html
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT
let's sat table name is **a**

```
select distinct on (setup_id,menu ) a.* from a;
```

Key point: The DISTINCT ON expression(s) must match the leftmost ORDER BY expression(s). The ORDER BY clause will normally contain additional expression(s) that **determine the desired precedence of rows within each DISTINCT ON group.**

Which means you can only **order by setup_id,menu** in this **distinct on query** scope.

Want the opposite:
**EXCEPT** returns all rows that are in the result of query1 but not in the result of query2. (This is sometimes called the difference between two queries.) Again, duplicates are eliminated unless **EXCEPT ALL** is used.

```
SELECT * FROM a
EXCEPT 
select distinct on (setup_id,menu ) a.* from a;
```

Answer (score 0):

For mysql the similar question is already answered here [Find and remove duplicate rows by two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14340820/find-and-remove-duplicate-rows-by-two-columns)

Try if any of the approach helps in this matter.

I like the below one for `MySql`:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE your_table ADD UNIQUE (SETUP_ID, MENU);
```

Comment: Im sorry...I dont know what was I thinking when I wrote Mysql...I meant postgresql for which this solution won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something along these lines to delete all but the first row in case of duplicates (please note that this is not tested in any way!):

```
DELETE FROM your_table WHERE id IN (
    SELECT unnest(duplicate_ids[2:]) FROM (
        SELECT array_agg(id) AS duplicate_ids FROM your_table
            GROUP BY SETUP_ID, MENU
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
        )
    )
)
```

The above collects the ids of the duplicate rows (`COUNT(*) > 1`) in an array (`array_agg`), then takes all but the first element in that array (`[2:]`) and "explodes" the id values into rows (`unnest`).
The outer query just deletes every id that ends up in that result.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE t1 
FROM table_name t1
    join table_name t2 on
    (t2.setup_id = t1.setup_id or t2.menu = t1.menu) and t2.id < t1.id
```

Comment: I think the first condition should read `(t2.setup_id = t1.setup_id AND t2.menu = t1.menu)` -- i.e. AND instead of OR.

Comment: ah ok exactly AND, because i'm not very fluent in english, so i don't understand the problem

Comment: This is not legal Postgres syntax.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to find and delete all duplicate row(s) based on conditions. But I like inner join method, which works very fast even in a large amount of Data. Please check follows :

```
DELETE T1 FROM <TableName> T1
INNER JOIN <TableName> T2 
WHERE
    T1.id > T2.id AND 
    T1.<ColumnName1> = T2.<ColumnName1> AND T1.<ColumnName2> = T2.<ColumnName2>;
```

In your case you can write as follows :

```
DELETE T1 FROM <TableName> T1
    INNER JOIN <TableName> T2 
    WHERE
        T1.id > T2.id AND 
        T1.setup_id = T2. setup_id;
```

Let me know if you face any issue or need more help.

Comment: Neither is legal Postgres syntax.